# is it possible to add multi-tenant features to a java application using hibernate 4 and EJB 3.1?

Tags: java, hibernate, jboss, ejb, multi-tenant

I'm new to asking questions on stackoverflow, but after a day of searching a solution to my problem, without success, I decided to ask.

Is it possible to add multi-tenancy features to a java EE applicatoion, using only Hibernate 4 and EJB 3.1 on jboss 7.1.1 final, without having to use Spring?

On the current project, i'm working on, i need to to implement a database strategy and i can't use spring for this. Does anyone know how to do so?

Comment: Is it a new project (= design phase) or maintenance (= already in production)?

Comment: the project is in maintenance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

multi-tenancy means very different things to different people.  You should probably explain what you mean specifically.

That said, Hibernate does have multi-tenancy support: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/devguide/en-US/html/ch16.html  An important note there is that Hibernate's support allows for cases where a "single running instance of an application simultaneously serves multiple clients (tenants)".  This is decidedly different, for example, from Java EE7's take on multi-tenancy where each tenant is served by a dedicated running instance of the application.

Comment: I have already read the hibernate documents and know that it supports multi-tenacy features. I need to make the application so that one instance of the application can serve multiple clients, on different databases( Database strategy). All the examples that i have found use Spring to get the tenant id and to ensure security, I would like to know if it is possible to do this with only hibernate and ejb with jpa anotations.

Comment: org.hibernate.context.spi.CurrentTenantIdentifierResolver is what you are looking for.  That is used, if defined, when opening Sessions (as Hibernate's JPA support does when building an EntityManager instance).  You would define this using the org.hibernate.cfg.AvailableSettings#MULTI_TENANT_IDENTIFIER_RESOLVER setting

Comment: thank you for your help, i will try your suggestion.